# How to load Bootstrap slider on base on click event (innerHTML javascript)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, innerhtml, bootstrap-slider

```js
function createslider(){
document.getElementById("loadSlider").innerHTML='<input id="ex1" data-slider-id="ex1Slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>';
}


// Without JQuery
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
 formatter: function(value) {
  return 'Current value: ' + value;
 }
});
```

```css
#ex1Slider .slider-selection {
 background: #BABABA;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.9.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.9.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.9.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>


<button onclick="createslider()"> Click me</button>


<div id="loadSlider">
<!--
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>-->

</div>
```

**Problem:** Bootstrap Slider is not display on click event javascript

**Explain:**
if i unhide slider HTML code (without onlclick event) its working fine but when i load  base on onlclick button slider is not display only input box is display

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript has one major flaw :

```
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }
});
```

nothing in your code calls this happen, the page will try to run the JS before the element with id `#ex1` exists because it will run on page load. Once you do the click event nothing tells it to associate the slider with it. You need to use a callback. Try the below javascript.

```
function createslider(){
document.getElementById("loadSlider").innerHTML='<input id="ex1" data-slider-id="ex1Slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>';
addNewSlider(); // let the callback attach the new slider once the new node has been added to the dom
}


// Without JQuery
function addNewSlider() { // callback at work
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }
});
}
```